# Why can a fpos_t * alias a FILE *?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, restrict-qualifier, pointer-aliasing

In Modern C, Jens Gustedt states that:

> With the exclusion of character types, only pointers of the same base type may alias.

But then I find this declaration of `fgetpos()` in Annex B of the C standard:

```
int fgetpos(FILE * restrict stream, fpos_t * restrict pos);
```

where the `fpos_t` type is defined as:

> which is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

which begs the question:

Why can a `fpos_t *` alias a `FILE *`? Is it because `fpos_t` can be a `typedef` for `FILE` ? If not, what justifies the use of `restrict` here?

Comment: They can't alias each other. I think the declaration uses `restrict` just to give the compiler as much information as possible. It's probably redundant.

Comment: Most (?) usages of the `restrict` qualifier in the standard library prototypes are for pointers with different base types, so there is nothing special here.

Comment: It also says, that the pointer you give from the callee, doesn't alias any other pointer of the same type in the callee's code.

Comment: If `FILE` constrains the same `fpos_t` member, than calling `fgetpos()` with those 2 violates due to `restrict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `restrict` in a function declaration that is not a definition has no effect in C semantics. C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 says parameter qualifiers are ignored when determining function compatibility, and that means the function could be declared with `restrict` on its parameters but defined without `restrict` or vice-versa. So the use of `restrict` in the documentation describing the routine is merely advice to the reader.

Normally, a `FILE` and `fpos_t` will not alias each other. (And note it is the **object** we are concerned about aliasing, not the **pointer**. The rules about aliasing in 6.5 7 are about what lvalue types may be used to access an object, not about pointers may be used [except of course when considering actually aliasing a pointer].) However, you could (in the sense it is possible, not advisable) have declared a union that contains both a `FILE` (if your C implementation defines it as a complete type) and a `fpos_t`, so you are passing in a properly prepared `FILE` object and are willing to have it sacrificed and replaced by an `fpos_t` in the same memory. You could also be doing this with dynamically allocated memory, since writing a new type (`fpos_t`) over an old type (`FILE`) is an allowed form of aliasing (when writing to dynamically allocated memory, whatever type you are using is the effective type, which is allowed for aliasing). So the `restrict` in the documentation for `fgetpos` is advising you not to do that.

Comment: Putting `restrict` in the documentation tells you that passing the same pointers for both may cause UB, right?

Comment: @Barmar: You would think, and that must be the intent, but I do not see it stated.

Comment: Perhaps this is more clearly stated in C23 then in C17/18: 6.7.4.2.8-9 _"The cost is that the programmer has to examine all those calls to ensure that none give undefined behavior. For example, the second call of `f` in `g` has undefined behavior because each of `d[1]` through `d[49]` is accessed through both `p` and `q`"_